# WebMatrix WebData InitializeDatabaseConnection

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I have placed the call to WebSecurity.InitializeDatabase in the _appstart.cshtml as noted in various google searches but periodically I keep receiving the below error when making subsequent calls to WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated for example, I would assume the initialisedatabase is called once for every user entering the website, is there a delay in this initialization before the _pagestart.cshtml is called?

```
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.VerifyInitialized()
at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.VerifyProvider()
at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Logout()
at ASP._Page__PageStart_cshtml.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there should not be a delay.

To use  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection, you call once ever with the parameter autoCreateTables= true.  After your tables are setup in your database, then from then on in _appstart, you'll call WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection with autoCreateTables = False.